# Split Array, then push arr out to individual Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a wheel of fortune type game in Javascript. If you look at the code,I am splitting the phrase array, and then creating a div to store the letter of the phrase. Here is where I am getting stuck.

How can I store the letters in a string from an array to individual divs. Therefore creating the effect of each letter has its own "square" or div.

```js
let phrases = [
    "Fish Out Of Water", "The Eifle Tower", "Berlin Syndrome", "bees", "arnold", "palmer"
];
function createDiv(parent,className){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = className;
    parent.appendChild(div);
    return div;
}
function loadPhrase(phrase) {
    let characters = [];
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
    let selectedPhrase = phrase[rand].split("");
    //display phrase to screen
console.log(selectedPhrase)

    let display = document.getElementById("display");
    let word = createDiv(display,'word');
    for (i = 0; i < selectedPhrase.length; i++){
        
        if(selectedPhrase[i] == ' '){
            characters.push(createDiv(word,'space'));
            word = createDiv(display, 'word');
        }else{
            characters.push(createDiv(word, 'letter'));

        }

    }


    console.log(characters)
};

loadPhrase(phrases)
```

```css
#display{
    background:blue;
    width:750px;
    margin:auto;
}
.word {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.letter {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.space{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
                


            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to append the letter using `div.innerHTML = letter` and also pass the `letter` while you are creating div. See the corrections i have made.

```js
let phrases = [
    "Fish Out Of Water", "The Eifle Tower", "Berlin Syndrome", "bees", "arnold", "palmer"
];
function createDiv(parent,className,letter = ''){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = className;
    div.innerHTML = letter;
    parent.appendChild(div);
    return div;
}
function loadPhrase(phrase) {
    let characters = [];
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
    let selectedPhrase = phrase[rand].split("");
    //display phrase to screen
//console.log(selectedPhrase)

    let display = document.getElementById("display");
    let word = createDiv(display,'word');
    for (i = 0; i < selectedPhrase.length; i++){
        
        if(selectedPhrase[i] == ' '){
            characters.push(createDiv(word,'space'));
            word = createDiv(display, 'word');
        }else{
            characters.push(createDiv(word, 'letter',selectedPhrase[i]));

        }

    }


    //console.log(characters)
};

loadPhrase(phrases)
```

```css
#display{
    background:blue;
    width:750px;
    margin:auto;
}
.word {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.letter {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.space{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As @Rick Hitchcock  pointed out strategy to initiale the `letter` variable doesn't currently work in IE

Comment: Great minds.  Good idea to initialize the `letter` parameter.

Comment: Initializing the `letter` parameter made me like this answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer ! Initializing in the parameter is a new technique I never knew you could do.

Comment: You may want to point out that initializing parameters doesn't work in IE, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Add a third parameter to the `createDiv` function, which will accept optional content to store in the div:

```
function createDiv(parent, className, content) {  //added ", content"
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = className;
  if(content) div.innerHTML = content;            //new code
  parent.appendChild(div);
  return div;
}
```

Then change your `else` clause as follows:

```
else {
  characters.push(createDiv(word, 'letter', selectedPhrase[i]));  //added ", selectedPhrase[i]"
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let phrases = [
    "Fish Out Of Water", "The Eifle Tower", "Berlin Syndrome", "bees", "arnold", "palmer"
];
function createDiv(parent, className, content) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = className;
    if(content) div.innerHTML = content;
    parent.appendChild(div);
    return div;
}
function loadPhrase(phrase) {
    let characters = [];
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
    let selectedPhrase = phrase[rand].split("");
    //display phrase to screen

    let display = document.getElementById("display");
    let word = createDiv(display,'word');
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedPhrase.length; i++){
        
        if(selectedPhrase[i] == ' '){
            characters.push(createDiv(word,'space'));
            word = createDiv(display, 'word');
        }else{
            characters.push(createDiv(word, 'letter', selectedPhrase[i]));

        }

    }
};

loadPhrase(phrases)
```

```css
#display{
    background:blue;
    width:750px;
    margin:auto;
}
.word {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.letter {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.space{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
                


            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! You helped me out just as much, I gave Johirul the answer, as it was the first one I saw. Both were equally good. (:

Comment: His answer is better since it initializes the parameter.  However, do note that it won't work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the value in your `createDiv` function and set using [`div.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) or [`div.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

**DEMO**

```js
let phrases = [
  "Fish Out Of Water", "The Eifle Tower", "Berlin Syndrome", "bees", "arnold", "palmer"
];

function createDiv(parent, className, text) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = text || '';
  div.className = className;
  parent.appendChild(div);
  return div;
}

function loadPhrase(phrase) {
  let characters = [];
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
  let selectedPhrase = phrase[rand].split("");
  //display phrase to screen
  //console.log(selectedPhrase)
  let display = document.getElementById("display");
  let word = createDiv(display, 'word');
  for (i = 0; i < selectedPhrase.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPhrase[i] == ' ') {
      characters.push(createDiv(word, 'space'));
      word = createDiv(display, 'word');
    } else {
      characters.push(createDiv(word, 'letter', selectedPhrase[i]));
    }
  }
};

loadPhrase(phrases)
```

```css
#display {
  background: blue;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
}

.word {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letter {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.space {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
</div>
```

---

One more way you can implement using using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
let phrases = ["Fish Out Of Water", "The Eifle Tower", "Berlin Syndrome", "bees", "arnold", "palmer"];

function loadPhrase(phrase) {
  let characters, index = 0,
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length),
    selectedPhrase = phrase[rand].split("");

  characters = selectedPhrase.reduce((r, v) => {
    if (v == ' ') {
      r[index] = (r[index] || '') + `<div class="space"></div>`;
      index++;
    } else {
      r[index] = (r[index] || '') + `<div class="letter">${v}</div>`;
    }
    return r;
  }, {});
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = Object.values(characters).map(v=>`<div class="word">${v}</div>`).join();
};

loadPhrase(phrases)
```

```css
#display {
  background: blue;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
}
.word {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letter {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.space {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```